# Vue 3 Vite Pinia Unit Testing - TypeError: [Function] is not a spy or a call to a spy! ONLY when running Coverage

Tags: vuejs3, vite, test-coverage, pinia, vitest

In my Vue 3 (using Vite and vi-test) app I am using Pinia and I've written some unit basic tests which run ok when I run

```
npm run test:unit
```

but when I run

```
npm run coverage
```

I get test errors:

```
TypeError: [Function] is not a spy or a call to a spy!
```

Anyone know why one would work but not the other?

This is my script setup in package.json:

```
"test:unit": "vitest --environment jsdom",
"coverage": "vitest run --coverage",
```

Here's an example of a test - this will run fine with the first command but with the second command will give the above error on the expect(store.clearCheckedData) line

```
describe("ContactBook", () => {

  let mockProps = {};
  let wrapper:any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = render(ContactBook, {
      props: mockProps,

      global: {
        components: {ProgressSpinner,Button,InputText,BaseButton},
        plugins: [PrimeVue,
          createTestingPinia({
            initialState: {contact:{
                mockRegistrationData: mockRegistrationData,
                loading: false,
              }},
            stubActions: false,
            createSpy: vi.fn,
            fakeApp:true
          }),
        ],
      },
    });
    setActivePinia(createPinia());
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });

  it("when Year / Reg Group tab is clicked, registrations component is rendered", async() => {
    const button = screen.getByText('Year / Reg Group')
    await userEvent.click(button);
    const store = useContactBookStore();
    expect(store.clearCheckedData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // ERROR ON THIS LINE
    expect(store.fetchRegistrationData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
    wrapper.getByTestId("registrations-component")
  });
```

Comment: Hmm, I just updated happy-dom to the latest version (7.6.6) and it seems to have fixed my issue!